# maintain activerecord relation when accessing relations through collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an activerecord relation object called contacts. Each contact model has_one lead. I want to return the leads as a relation and therefore I cannot use map,collect,select.

Obviously, this doesn't work because the iterator breaks the relation:

```
contacts.select(&:lead)
```

This works but returns contacts as the relation object, not leads:

```
contacts.joins(:lead)
```

Therefore when I try to invoke the group_by_week activerelation method on the result:

```
contacts.joins(:lead).group_by_week(:created_at).size
```

created_at refers to contacts, whereas I want it to refer to leads.

Comment: Why can't you use map?

Comment: @japed if I use map, I get this error: TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when running this: contacts.map(&:lead).group_by_week(:created_at).size because group_by_week expects a relation not array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just do it like this:

```
leads = Lead.where(contact_id: contacts)
```

If that fails you might need to select the id's of the contacts and pass those in.

```
leads = Lead.where(contact_id: contacts.map(&:id))
```